# Interactive bar chart.user changes y axis value at runtime by dragging it

Tags: charts, interactive

For example 3 columns are there with y axis value as 100,200,300 in barcharts.
User select one column alone and drag it to 500 value in y-axis.
How to achieve this?
Is it available in library like androidplot or aChartPlugin?
If not which plugin support this requirement.Our project is for Android tablets
Please provide me sample code for this requirement.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found little bit similar requirement in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HHLrF/. But how can we do this with android using libraries like androidPlot or aChartPlugin?or any other plugin which supports android with this feature

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge no library exists for Android that provides 'out of the box' capabilities to drag and reorganize data.  Having said that, any library that provides you with a way to correlate touch events to data elements and also supports dynamic updates should be suitable.

If you have specific requirements about how the "drag" is implemented then you may end up having to roll your own library or customize an existing one to your needs.  If not, here's a basic workflow you could implement with Androidplot that represents the drag operation as a cursor:

1 - Detect selections using an OnTouchListener.  [Here's an example](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/BarPlotExampleActivity.java?at=master#cl-154) of a bar plot that allows bar selection via touch.  Gives a full example of converting screen coords to model elements etc.  Create and add an instance of [XValueMarker](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/xy/XValueMarker.java?at=master) denoting the current position of the selection. (An XValueMarker is basically a customizable vertical line marking an x-val.

2 - Detect "drag" events using an OnTouchListener.  [Here's an example](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/TouchZoomExampleActivity.java?at=master#cl-144) that detects zooming and scrolling.  It's not the same thing exactly but the scrolling logic is close enough to give you the general idea.

3 - As the user drags, update the position of the XValueMarker by [XValueMarker.setValue(Number)](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/xy/ValueMarker.java?at=master#cl-96).

4 - Once the "drag" ends, remove the XValueMarker and modify the underlying XYSeries to reflect the change using basic data structure manipulation(s).

And of course remember to always call plot.redraw() after each operation that is expected to alter the appearance of the plot in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But iam very new to android platform.I created Bar Chart using aChartEngine plugin. Any sample code implementing the dragging feature like this http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/  with aChartPlugin or Androidplot plugin would be very useful for me. One more question i found this dragging feature in highcharts plugin.But how to integrate highcharts plugin in android?any tutorial link will be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But Highcharts is paid not freesource it seems.I want to implement with any opensource library which supports android.could anyone please help with sample code to do this.